# CSS wrapping issue

Tags: css

Am having 2 span and  to display in UI like below

```
span1:The example will show you how to implement a span  (Span2)
```

but if my span 2 length is too long i want it like below

```
span1:The example will show you how to 
      implement a too long span (Span2)
```

What css should i use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you could use: `max-width:300px;`

Answer (score 0):

try this  `word-wrap: break-word;`